# move default docker container to another place on the disk

Tags: performance, docker, builder

We are trying to figure out how to change the target place of the docker container. By default it is created in  /var/lib/docker/containers.
    Lets say  I would like to move it to /tmp/docker.
    All I could find so far was the docker volumes but it is not doing the thing the purpose of this usage is different.

What we want to do is to place the container in the RAM memory of the server so we can significantly reduce the time spent for building binaries.

Is it possible?

Regards,
Jordan

Comment: If you want to reduce the time spent, use a local registry, see http://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/ and use apt-cacher-ng https://docs.docker.com/examples/apt-cacher-ng/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*There appears to be a -g command line option, I don't really understand why it is called graph...*

It has been deprecated and renamed to --data-root.

```
--data-root /var/lib/docker              Path to use as the root of the Docker runtime
```

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/

```
mkdir /tmp/docker && docker --data-root /var/lib/docker /tmp/docker ...
```

Answer (score 8):

See by @thaJeztah https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3127

It's also possible to use a `daemon.json` configuration file instead of `/etc/default/docker`. The `/etc/default/docker` is only used for systems running upstart, and not for systems running systemd, so is more portable. Also it allows reloading some configuration settings without restarting the daemon;

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-configuration-file

E.g

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1, but it shouldn't matter because this is a cross-distro solution.

Just put this json into `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
"data-root": "/path/to/docker"
}
```

For the older versions it was "graph" option:

```
{
"graph": "/path/to/docker"
}
```

Worked for me and I didn't have to mess with upstart or systemd.

Answer (score 2):

We tried the following steps to Docket container folder to different folder:

Stop Docker service

1. chkconfig docker off
2. reboot the server
3. copy files /var/lib/docker to /targetfolder/docker using 
   rsync -a --sparse --progress /var/lib/docker /apps/docker
4. Edit Configuration : /lib/systemd/system/docker.service 
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /targetfolder/docker/
5. mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker1  (for backup)
6. ln -s /targetfolder/docker /var/lib/docker  (optional - )

7.chkconfig docker on

8.systemctl daemon-reload

9.systemctl restart docker

10. Start your old containers by referring this command --> docker ps -a

Comment: This sounds great !

Answer (score -1):

Stop docker service:

```
service docker stop
```

Move your containers folder to your ssd:

```
mv /var/lib/docker/containers /mnt/ssd_example/
```

Create symlink to default docker container folder:

```
ln -s /mnt/ssd_example/containers/ /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Start docker service:

```
service docker start
```

Comment: Definitely go with the --graph option to the daemon rather than symlinks.